# Merge two rows into one in a CSV file in JAVA

Tags: java

I have a CSV with that format:

```
FASS339XM;4567;false;89590343<br>
940000299;4183;2019-09-02 14:12:18.461819;HW;0986481366<br>
FADS339XM;4446;true;89594343<br>
940000300;4183;2019-09-02 14:12:21.243148;HW;0986481366<br>
FASS339XM;4567;true;89590343<br>
940000301;4183;2019-09-03 09:58:17.173558;HW;0009482803<br>
...
```

I need to join the blocks of two different rows into one like this:

```
FASS339XM;4567;false;89590343;940000299;4183;2019-09-02 14:12:18.461819;HW;0986481366
FADS339XM;4446;true;89594343;940000300;4183;2019-09-02 14:12:21.243148;HW;0986481366
FASS339XM;4567;true;89590343;940000301;4183;2019-09-03 09:58:17.173558;HW;0009482803
```

I have no idea of what to do. I tried in a several ways but I couldn't do it.
I develop in JAVA and Spring Batch.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could just read the file line-by-line and write each pair of lines to a single line instead.

Comment: Or you can make an spring batch with an two line per token reader, an processor thad concat and clean you two line, and a writer that write the transformed line.

Comment: Pls describe what you tried until now with pieces of code reflecting that. Then ... please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Finally please read this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
try (PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter("path/to/output.csv");) {
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("path/to/your.csv"));
    // assuming your csv has an even number of lines
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
        output.println(lines.get(i) + ";" + lines.get(++i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works!! Just add an EOL al the end of  output.write(lines.get(i) + ";" + lines.get(++i)) because it creates a file with unique row.

Comment: Sorry, `println` is what I intended.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a quick and dirty sed command

```
sed -z -e "s/<br>\n\([^F]\)/;\1/g" -e "s/<br>//g" -i <file>
```